# Selenium - Unable to find element with xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I am trying to find an element on [this](https://www.trustnet.com/factsheets/o/g6ia/ishares-global-property-securities-equity-index-uk) page. Specifically the bid price in the first row: **196.20p**.

I am using selenium and this is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
address = 'https://www.trustnet.com/factsheets/o/g6ia/ishares-global-property-securities-equity-index-uk'
xpath = '//*[@id="factsheet-tabs"]/fund-tabs/div/div/fund-tab[3]/div/unit-details/div/div/unit-information/div/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]'
price = driver.find_element_by_xpath(asset['xpath'])
print price.text
driver.close()
```

When executed I receive the following error

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with xpath '//*[@id=\"factsheet-tabs\"]/fund-tabs/div/div/fund-tab[3]/div/unit-details/div/div/unit-information/div/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]'","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"214","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:62727","User-Agent":"Python http auth"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\": \"xpath\", \"sessionId\": \"8faaff70-af12-11e7-a17c-416247c75eb6\", \"value\": \"//*[@id=\\\"factsheet-tabs\\\"]/fund-tabs/div/div/fund-tab[3]/div/unit-details/div/div/unit-information/div/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/8faaff70-af12-11e7-a17c-416247c75eb6/element"}}
Screenshot: available via screen
```

I have used the same approach, but with different xpath, on [yahoo finance](https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/quote/GB00B5BFJG71.L?p=GB00B5BFJG71.L) and it works fine, but unfortunately the price I am looking for is not available there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I didn't fail to understand your requirement then this is the price you wanted to scrape. I used css selector here.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.trustnet.com/factsheets/o/g6ia/ishares-global-property-securities-equity-index-uk')
price = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[ng-if^="$ctrl.priceInformation.Mid"] td:nth-child(2)').text
print(price.split(" ")[0])
driver.quit()
```

Result:

```
196.20p/196.60p
```

If you wanna stick to xpath then try this:

```
price = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@ng-if,"$ctrl.priceInformation.Mid")]//td[2]').text
```

Comment: I have accepted the answer as it answers the original question. A couple of comments though. 1. It seems to be much slower than xpath; is that normal? 2. It does not work with PhantomJS. Thanks

Comment: It varies a little if there is a speed related issue. Few say css selector is better to go with because it is easy to read and understand and few recommend xpath as it has the ability to traverse Dom in the way you expect. However, to get a clear idea you might wanna track down http://elementalselenium.com/tips/32-xpath-vs-css this link.